# C# XAML Master Detail Binding does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, master-detail

I want to display a List in a ListView with Master Detail View. The Master View works fine, but the binding to the detail view is not working. What am i doing wrong?

Code Behind:

```
DataContext = new VirtualizingCollection<LinesSummary>(fs, 100)
```

LinesSummary Class:

```
public class LinesSummary {

     public string dateString { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView Margin="5" Style="{DynamicResource lvStyle}" Height="200" x:Name="Master"/>
        <ListView Margin="5" Style="{DynamicResource lvStyle_Detail}" Height="200" x:Name="Detail"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Dynamic Resource for Master View:

```
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding}"/>
        <Setter Property="ListView.View">
            <Setter.Value>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dateString}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Dynamic Resource for Detail View:

```
    <Style x:Key="lvStyle_Detail" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ListView.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ElementName=Master, Path=SelectedItem.LinesSummary}"/>
        <Setter Property="ListView.View">
            <Setter.Value>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="aaa" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dateString}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: What's the type of myList and how is the class defined?

Comment: Why is the `ItemsSource` of your detail view `Path=SelectedItem.LinesSummary` and not `Path=SelectedItem`?

Comment: @mm8: myList is a self created Collection that inherits from IList

Comment: @MightyBadaboom I tried it with Path=SelectedItem. Did not work

Comment: And how and where is LinesSummary defined?

Comment: LinesSummary is the name of a member of my List. It contains for example the string value dateString

Comment: It should be an item of the SelectedItem. The SelectedItem property doesn't refer to the list...post your class.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I added some info in the section "Code Behind" and added the class LinesSummary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemsSource` of a `ListView` can only be bound to an `IEnumerable` so even if you bind the `ItemsSource` property of the second `ListView` like this it won't work:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Master, Path=SelectedItem}"
```

...because `LinesSummary` is not an `IEnumerable`.

Since there is only a maximum of one item selected in `Master`, you might as well bind a `TextBlock` to the `dateString` property of its `SelectedItem`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView Margin="5" Style="{DynamicResource lvStyle}" Height="200" x:Name="Master"/>
    <ListView Margin="5" Style="{DynamicResource lvStyle_Detail}" Height="200" x:Name="Detail">
        <ListViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.dateString, ElementName=Master}" />
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Remove this setter from the `lvStyle_Detail`:

```
<Setter Property="ListView.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ElementName=Master, Path=SelectedItem.LinesSummary}"/>
```

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you!